# is there a way to set "WONT NAWS" with "telnet" command?

Tags: linux, telnet

I turned on displaying of options with .telnetrc file:

```
DEFAULT
   toggle options
```

And then I run telnet and among the options it displays:

```
SENT WILL NAWS
SENT IAC SB NAWS 0 100 (100) 0 93 (93)
```

Is there a way to set "WONT NAWS"?  The system I'm connecting to doesn't handle it.  (It ignores the columns setting and defaults to 80, thus injecting CR/LF characters.  I know that if we "WONT NAWS", it will stop injecting CR/LF characters.)

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one implementation.  To answer the question, you probably have to read the source code.  For example,

- the Debian package for telnet in "jessie" is [telnet (0.17-36)](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/telnet)
- the corresponding source is available for download [http://netkit-telnet_0.17.orig.tar.gz](http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/n/netkit-telnet/netkit-telnet_0.17.orig.tar.gz)
- in the source, the option is sent unconditionally, as seen in `telnet.cc`:

```
      if (telnetport) {
        send_do(TELOPT_SGA, 1);
        send_will(TELOPT_TTYPE, 1);
        send_will(TELOPT_NAWS, 1);
        send_will(TELOPT_TSPEED, 1);
        send_will(TELOPT_LFLOW, 1);       
        send_will(TELOPT_LINEMODE, 1);
        send_will(TELOPT_ENVIRON, 1);   
        send_do(TELOPT_STATUS, 1);
        if (env_getvalue("DISPLAY", 0))
          send_will(TELOPT_XDISPLOC, 1);
        if (eight)           
          tel_enter_binary(eight);
      }
```

Of course, having the source, you can modify it and make that feature configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the answer to your response is **do nothing**

If you read telnet protocol `RFC-854`, you'll se that `WILL`, `DO`, `WONT`, `DONT` are option negotiations that only announce options you are willing to accept (or to configure in the peer).  If the server doesn't accept those options, you'll receive a `DONT` response (to a `WILL`) and a `WONT` (to a `DO`), and option will not be negotiated.  `TELNET` is a robust protocol, designed for maximum interoperability and as so, it only allows negotiation of options understood a both end, while being extensible enough to allow almost infinite extension possibilities.  The only reason you can have to, by-force disallow an option, is when both ends understand it, both ends default behaviour is to negotiate it, and you don't want that option to be set  (an example being the passing of selected environment variables to the other end, which is normally configured with a command line option).

All telnet options have a default value designed to be non-negotiated in case one of the ends doesn't support it.  So you are in no risk, at least emerging from the `TELNET` protocol.

By the way, which was the answer from the server to the `WILL NAWS`.  Whas it a `DO NAWS`? or was it `DONT NAWS`? (this last should be the *I don't support NAWS* response from the server you should receive in case `NAWS` is not a supported feature)